# Ignore irregular CSV file rows on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm downloading a CSV file from a url and so far so good, the problem is that they have changed the format of the file a little bit and now the last row contains only text, so it only has one column, when normal is 7, so I get the following error:

```
Fields num seems to be 7 on each row, but on 820th csv row, fields num is 1.
```

Right now I just tried it and it works because they have already changed the excel file and they have added at the end of that row the necessary commas to make it work well, but, in case it happens again, is there any way that through code I can include those commas or another way to solve it? I leave you my code:

```
            try {
                val rows: List<List<String>> = csvReader().readAll(URL(CASES_FILE_URL).openStream())
                val listCCAA: List<CasesModel> = rows.map {
                    CasesModel(it [0], it [1], it [2], it [3], it [4], it [5], it [6])
                }
                val lastDate: String = listCCAA.map { it.date }.last { it.isNotEmpty() }
                val finalItems = listCCAA.filter { lastDate == it.date }
                casesRepositoryLiveDataContract.onSuccess(finalItems)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```